# How is standard input displayed on a terminal?

Tags: display, terminal, stdin

According to the Wikipedia article on standard streams, The keyboard is connected to a program via standard input. I'm assuming the program refers to a shell, which interprets the commands inputted by the keyboard. My question: How are my inputs displayed on screen if they redirected to a program? Hopefully you can correct me for any misunderstanding I may have.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you see it now? I don't get what part you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs are displayed to you by the terminal / program / operating system / host. If it is configured not to do so, you will see nothing on your screen.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(computing) is probably the lecture you want next.

Comment: It seems that a terminal would perform a local echo to its display! I think this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: There are 3 main file descriptors (streams) standard in, standard out, and standard error.  The program will write to one of these descriptors.  without any redirection, your terminal will display any of these to the screen.  I'd visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams before echo personally.

Comment: I reread your question and see you came from there already.  The answer is that the program would use C library functions which are essentially wrappers for system calls which would write to the respective file descriptor (0,1,2) and thusly the stream which would show up in your terminal.

Comment: echo ultimately uses the write system call.  See this trace of the command "echo helloThere!" write(1, "helloThere!\n", 12helloThere!
) Which uses the file descriptor 1 (standard output stream to write the 12 byte string to my terminal, followed by a newline.